# How do I format c++ comments properly?

Tags: c++

Could anyone please suggest a proper format of comments I should use in a C++ project? I think that there is some analog of [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/) format, but I can't find which one. Is there any de-facto standard of that kind? Thanks!

Comment: Corollary: http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Comments

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) is used rather frequently for C++ projects (Doxygen supports other languages as well). You can use Doxygen-style comments as a starting point ([here are some examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen#Example_code)). Just be consistent.

Comment: +1, I consider doxygen to be a *de facto* standard for documentation comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your mention of javadoc suggests you might be thinking of [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).  This is a kit which supports structured comments in C++ and other languages, and can produce output in HTML and (if I recall correctly) PDF.  It supports a variety of comment styles, including one which looks very much like javadoc.

It works well, and is broadly used.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite controversial as a subject in every language.

While I appreciate the Doxygen answers, since it's effectively kind of a de facto standard, Doxygen itself supports multiple formats.

C++ supports 2 styles of comments:

- `/**/` multi-line comment
- `//` until the end of line comment

I would advise not to use the former style. The issue is that it does not nest, which is quite annoying when for testing purpose you wish to comment out a whole block of code.

My 2 cents, as the saying goes.

Comment: Although disabling code for testing is often better done with `#if 0` / `#endif`.